# Can you (and should you) disambiguate a function call taking T and const reference to T?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

If we have:

```
void foo(int) {}
void foo(const int&) {}
```

we cannot call `foo` like this:

```
foo(3);
```

because the call is ambiguous:

> ```
> error: call of overloaded 'foo(int)' is ambiguous
> 40 |     foo(3);
>    |          ^
> note: candidate: 'void foo(int)'
> 36 | void foo(int) {}
>    |      ^~~
> note: candidate: 'void foo(const int&)'
> 37 | void foo(const int&) {}
>    |      ^~~
> ```

What we can do is explicitly provide the correct overload, for example via a function pointer:

```
auto (*ptr)(const int&) -> void = foo;
ptr(3); // calls the "const int&" overload, obviously
```

However, that kind of defeats the purpose of convenient overloads. The question is - can I somehow disambiguate the call in a more... *elegant?* way? Are there **ever** cases where it would be desired to provide **both** overloads, for `T` and for `const T&`?

Comment: Using a function pointer would be the cleanest solution.  You could type-cast `foo` itself, and that works, but that is not very readable: `static_cast<void (*)(const int&)>(foo)(3);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you. I am, however, way more interested in the last part of the question - apologies for not emphesising that well enough. But having read your comment I am starting to believe that there would not be a reason to provide overloads for both `T&` and `const T&`, am I correct?

Comment: *"Are there ever cases where it would be desired to provide both overloads, for T and for const T&?"* - You know, I was about to ask *you* that. Because I've yet to encounter a situation where the need arose.

Comment: Regardless of whether there is a real use case for this, I would still like to know the answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the question is purely academic - I didn't feel that my opinion alone could be a sufficient answer, because I have never researched this topic up until an hour ago. I didn't find anything which would indicate that it would be desired, so I wanted to confirm this with SO experts. Your suspicion, if I can call it like that, is absolutely correct.

Comment: FWIW, you can change the overload set from `void foo(int) {} void foo(const int&) {}` to `void foo(int&) {} void foo(int&&) {}` and now the first is called with lvalues and the second with rvalues.

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit templates. Overload resolution favours a non-template function over a template one, so converting one of the overloads to a template is a sufficent disambiguation:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int n)
{
    std::cout << "By Value  " << n;
}

template<int N = 0>
void foo(const int& n)
{
    std::cout << "By Reference " << n;
}

int main() {
    foo(1);
    foo<>(1);
}
```

Granted, you need `<>` to call the template one, but this could have some uses. Ostensibly more elegant than a function pointer? But alas it's not really much better than renaming say `foo<>` to `bar`.

Comment: Interesting, but I am not sure that passes the elegance test.

Comment: @wcochran, come on, what's a `<>` between friends?

Comment: This works even if we drop the `const&` part, so, while it shows an interesting tool (upvoted), doesn't address the question close enough, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're asking whether we can force the overload resolution mechanism to select one signature over the other, rather than explicitly spelling out the signature that you want.

As far as I know, the only way to force overload resolution to pick the `int` overload over the `const int&` overload is to cast the argument to a `volatile int` glvalue, and there is no way to force overload resolution to pick the `const int&` overload over the `int` overload.

In any case, I can't think of any reason why one would want to write this particular set of overloads.

Answer (score 1):

> we cannot call foo like this: `foo(3);` because the call is ambiguous

In general, that's exactly why developers avoid providing overloads *that* similar. That makes it hard to use the overloads. Generally developers will have a `const T&` and a `T&&` overload, since those are never ambiguous.

> However, that kind of defeats the purpose of convenient overloads.

The purpose of convenient overloads is to allow the calling code to easily call the right function.  Calling exactly one is *fulfilling* the purpose of convenient overloads. The annoyance of casting to a function pointer is a side effect of having overloads too close togeather and is not normal.

The only exception I can think of is when you want to pass an overloaded set of functions to something else as a functoid, and let *that* caller pick which overload it wants.

```
struct foo_functoid {
    void operator()(int v) {foo(v);}
    void operator()(const int& v) {foo(v);}
};
//or
struct foo_functoid {
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T&& v) {foo(std::forward<T>(v));}
};
```

But unfortunately, for these functoids, there is no shortcut, they must be written explicitly by hand (with possibly minor assistance from macros)

Comment: "*However, that kind of defeats the purpose of convenient overloads.*" - I meant that in reference to the `auto (*ptr)(const int&) -> void = foo; ptr(3);` part.

Comment: I edited that section to be clearer that casting to a pointer is a side effect of having  overloads too close together and is not normal.